# Start a script before all in Unity (Script Execution Order doen't work)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, order-of-execution

I handle all player's data in one script called "binaryStorage". When the game starts, in the first scene, I have put the player's total points, the problem is that when the script that handles all this scene try to get the player's total points, it gets the 0 value (because it call the method "getPlayerPoints" inside the script 'binaryStorage' before that script has been initialized).

To fix this I tried to edit the script execution order of 'binaryStorage', editing the default time by '100' to '90' but nothing changes, the script that handles the scene ever starts before this.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try changing the time of `binaryStorage` to -1 instead of 90.

Comment: "The script that handles all this" is not the same as "binary Storage"? Also, fix the punctuation in your question. It is quite confusing.

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg, thank you so much, it worked! Why -1? if every script starts at 100 why -1 is better that 90 or any number smaller than 100?

Comment: I think every script starts at 0 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script Execution `default` time is `0`

So setting a script time to `-1` will execute it before the `default` time.

Image illustrates the execution order of `-1`, `default`, `1` and `100`
[image]

Comment: I thought that the default time was 0